# How to set a value for custom SIP Header in Asterisk and how to get it in PHP?

Tags: php, asterisk

its first time i use astersik and first time i use php too.
 i use Asterisk 12 and i want to add a SIP Header with a value in my php code and transfer call to another asterisk server and get my SIP Header.

```
---------------------------php code in server a-------------------------
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
  require('phpagi.php'); 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $agi = new AGI();
  $agi->answer();
  //I want to set a Sip Header here  
  //for example set OrderId = 5566
  $agi-> exec("DIAL SIP/omid/3444");
  ?>
```

and when call transfred to server b i want to get my SIP Header

```
---------------------------php code in server b-------------------------
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
   require('phpagi.php');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $agi = new AGI();
   $agi->answer();
   //Get OrderId from SIP Header and show it
   //$agi->Verbose('OrderId:'.$orderIdFromHeader);
   $agi->hangup();

?>
```

Comment: please,  show us , the code you written .

Comment: i added my code, now you could see it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't add  header from php.

You can do it via dialplan using

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show applications like header
    -= Matching Asterisk Applications =-
          SIPAddHeader: Add a SIP header to the outbound call. 
       SIPRemoveHeader: Remove SIP headers previously added with SIPAddHeader 
    -= 2 Applications Matching =-
```

For use dialplan you should dial via channel type **Local**, not SIP.

You can read header using function:

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show functions like HEADER
Matching Custom Functions:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SIP_HEADER            SIP_HEADER(name[,number])            Gets the specified SIP header from an incoming INVITE message. 
1 matching custom functions installed.
```

In your case usually used CALLERID(name) for send info, that way your agent will see order id on phones.